# c# Generic method call to static function

Tags: c#, generics, static

I have a generic method in a class as follows

```
    private static Dictionary<Type, Feed> _singletons = new Dictionary<Type, Feed>();

    public static Feed GetFeed<T>() where T:Feed
    {    
        lock(_padlock)
        {
            if (!_singletons.ContainsKey(typeof(T))
            {                   
                _singletons[typeof(T)] = typeof(T).GetInstance();
            }
            return _singletons[typeof(T)];          
        }
    }
```

Here, `Feed` is an interface and `Type` is of types of classes that implement the `Feed` interface. `GetInstance()` is a static method in these classes. Is there something wrong with `typeof(T).GetInstance();`? It says `System.Type` does not contain a definition for `GetInstance()`.

Comment: Because `typeof()` returns a `Type` object. The `Type` class doesn't have such a method.

Comment: Yes. That part I get. So what is the alternative to this call?

Comment: The `typeof(T)` operator returns an instance of `System.Type`, not an instance of `T`. Now with that being said, I think you should really consider re-writing whatever you're trying to do. Singleton is a very nasty anti-pattern, and combined with reflection magic, seems like you're setting yourself up for an application of questionable maintainability. Ask yourself what advantage you get with your type dictionary: why would a client write `var x = Feeds.GetFeed<MyFeedImpl>()` instead of `var x = new MyFeedImpl()`?

Comment: This is part of a factory pattern

Comment: Coolness :) I would still recommend making your factory method non-static, and returning new instances of your classes rather than evil singletons. Factories are meant to put a layer of indirection between an object instance and its constructor, so that the object which gets created can vary independently of whoever uses the factory (i.e. like a LogFactory class that returns a FileLogger or DbLogger based on configuration). Static factory methods prevent reduce testability, and specifying the concrete type returned from factory seems weird since `Feeds.GetFeed<X>()` == `X.GetInstance()`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use Reflection to call a static method like so:

```
private static Dictionary<Type, Feed> _singletons = new Dictionary<Type, Feed>();

public static Feed GetFeed<T>() where T:Feed
{    
    lock(_padlock)
    {
        if (!_singletons.ContainsKey(typeof(T))
        {                   
            return typeof(T).GetMethod("GetInstance", System.Reflection.BindingFlags.Static).Invoke(null,null);

        }
        return _singletons[typeof(T)];          
    }
}
```

Comment: You'll need BindingFlags.Public as well.

Answer (score 2):

The simplest way is to use the `new` constraint

```
private static Dictionary<Type, Feed> _singletons = new Dictionary<Type, Feed>();

public static Feed GetFeed<T>() where T:Feed, new()
{    
    lock(_padlock)
    {
        if (!_singletons.ContainsKey(typeof(T))
        {                   
            _singletons[typeof(T)] = new T();
        }
        return _singletons[typeof(T)];          
    }
}
```